# Played out across the rock

Tags: spelling, listening

In this video
http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/oct/22/us-special-forces-free-kurdish-hostages-isis-iraq

The video on top from the time 2:11 to 2:15

Does he say "played out across the rock"?

I could not find the meaning anywhere..

Comment: Are you a native speaker, or is English your second language?

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost it is my second language

Comment: Yeah, several other languages (that don't have /θ/ and /ð/) mix up between the sibilant sounds /s/ and /z/ and the dental fricative sounds /θ/ and /ð/, among *other* confusions. You might have heard a dental fricative there (i.e. the "th" in "the") when it was actually a transition between /s/ and the first vowel of "Iraq".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misheard it. He's saying "played out across **Iraq**".

Comment: Thanks! I spent time to find the meaning of the wrong word...indeed he is saying Iraq.